# SVG use defs not work on chrome 46

Tags: google-chrome, svg

The use tag in my SVG works on Chrome latest versions (58, 59, maybe 50+),
but not work on Chrome 46 (maybe 40+). why?

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <g id="diamond" viewBox="0 0 120 60" enable-background="new 0 0 120 60">
            <path d="M 11 -24 L 44 -6 Q 55 0 44 6
                    L 11 24 Q 0 30 -11 24
                    L -44 6 Q -55 0 -44 -6
                    L -11 -24 Q 0 -30 11 -24" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="2px" stroke-miterlimit="10"></path>
        </g>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <use href="#diamond" transform="translate(60,30)" class="diamond" style="opacity: 1;"></use>
    
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Absolutely... Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to write href rather than xlink:href is fairly new. It's a part of the SVG 2 specification. The SVG 1.1 specification only defines xlink:href.

If you need to target old browsers, or Safari, you'll need to use xlink:href as well or instead of href.